# Error: Unexpected value 'CookieService' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, ngx-cookie-service

I'm trying to test a service with jasmine but i have this error:

Error: Unexpected value 'CookieService' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

and

Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.

My spec file:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Api } from './api.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

fdescribe('ApiService', () => {
  let service: Api;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        Api,

      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        CookieService
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.inject(Api);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message shows as `CookieServie` is not a `NgModule`.

> Error: Unexpected value 'CookieService' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

As [Ngx-Cookie documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service),

> Add the cookie service to your app.module.ts as a provider:

---

### Solution

You have to remove `CookieService` from `imports` section and add it into `providers` section.

> .spec.ts

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    Api,
    CookieService
 ],
 imports: [
   HttpClientTestingModule,
   RouterTestingModule
 ],
 schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
});
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gu8l9r?file=src/services/api.service.spec.ts)

Comment: great, but i have a new problem XD, this is: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Api -> CookieService -> CookieOptionsProvider -> CookieOptionsProvider]: 
   NullInjectorError: No provider for CookieOptionsProvider!

Comment: You need to add `CookieModule.forRoot()` into `imports` section. You may refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie/issues/10).